# Excel Power View Date Slicer

Tags: excel, powerview

I am trying to create a date slicer in Excel Power View. My query is pulling from Salesforce to show data from the past 60 Days. I would like to create a slicer to only show data for Past 7 Days, Past 30 Days, and Past 60 Days.

This is easy to do as just a simple pivot table, but I am unable to figure out how to create this in Power View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Power View to create these buckets as slicers. These buckets must be defined in your source. However, you could use Power View to add those buckets as filters using the advanced filter options. But if you add a filter to show only the last 7 days data the filter would just be tied to a specific date. These filters won't be dynamic unless you have flagged the data at source.